# You don't have permission to access /customer/account/create/ on this server

Tags: magento-1.9

We upgraded magento to 1.9.3.3. Now, We are not able to create account. It says "You don't have permission to access /customer/account/create/ on this server."

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've found that the server blocked the url.

If someone runs the same problem I guess it is worth asking hosting provider.